# 13.04 and dual monitors

Tags: 13.04, multiple-monitors

Sorry, but I really didn't know where to put this.
I actually wanted to warn that using a VGA or HDMI cable to connect to a second screen or TV gives a very messy image and doesn't work correctly at all. The best it can do is to mirror what is on my screen, after some weird image bug.
If there's a better place to post this problem, let me know, please.

Comment: I'd suspect VGA drivers malfunction rather than kernel issue

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on my mac with Radeon X1600 card. My screen is connected via DVI cable and when I use keyboard to switch apps or use search option both screens act strange. For now my only solution is to use mirror screen option or only one screen. It is graphic driver problem.

Answer (score 0):

It had the same problem on 11.04 and aparently it was never fixed... The best thing if you don't want to change any system settings is to go back to 10.04. Trust me if you want dual screen in high resolution it's the best you can do. Also there is not much change between those version.